# Text-box Functions

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to make this the same thing, as you can see one has the comma, but the other has not only the text box that does not have the comma is that it works I wanted that of the comma also worked.

[image]

[image]

I have this code and when I use a comma it show me the error message box, that 
should not happen.

```
 MessageBox.Show("resultou", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Int64 ValFromTextBox;
            if (!Int64.TryParse(descarregar.Text, out ValFromTextBox))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Errou");
                // TELL USER NOT A NUMBER OR SOMETHING
            }
            MessageBox.Show("resultou", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            string text = (ValFromTextBox * 100).ToString("-000000000");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\movedir\SUBTOTALE.txt", text);
            string move1 = @"C:\movedir\SUBTOTALE.txt";
            string move2 = @"C:\Cashmatic\SUBTOTALE.txt";
            System.IO.File.Move(move1, move2); 
        }
```

Comment: In a textbox you can enter anything, so they both "work" ask an actual question now please

Comment: I guess, you're looking for `MaskedTextbox`

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I just don't get it clear what you want. Are you looking for MaskedTextbox or NumericUpDown or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem related to comma in the Textbox is because you are using an `Int64.TryParse()`, so the expected value are an integer...

When you use a value with comma, isn't a integer value anymore, so you need to use `Double.TryParse()` or `Decimal.TryParse()`.

But, even using this, I recomend you to use a **MaskedTextbox** (like described in the comments), so you don't need to worry about handling if the user inputs a comma or a dot.